# How to generate test plan for quiz in moodle?

Tags: jmeter, moodle

I am new to Moodle, I have installed Moodle 3.4.I need to do performance testing using Jmeter.Can I get steps to generate test plan in moodle so that I can use same test plan in Jmeter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest and the easiest way of building a JMeter test plan for a web application is just recording it using [JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium/)

Once you record the test plan "skeleton" you will need to perform some [correlation of dynamic parameters and parameterization of i.e. credentials or answers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start).

There is also [JMeter test plan generator](https://docs.moodle.org/38/en/JMeter_test_plan_generator) utility if you need to test overall performance, not custom scenario, see https://github.com/moodlehq/moodle-performance-comparison/blob/master/README.md for more details.